# Return large amount of JavaScript from a PHP function that includes quotation marks

Tags: javascript, php, return

I have the following function in php, it takes an argument and is meant to output the javascript code with the argument inside.

Two issues I have:

1. The return encapsulates the javascript code with quotation marks, however the quotation marks within the javascript code itself is actually causing it to cut off early.
2. The $ marks in the javascript are not working because I think the jquery $ marks are being seen as a php $, is there any way I can make the dollar sign and quotation marks in the javascript code segment not confuse php?

   ```
   function returnJS($input){

   return "    

       $("#toggle1").click(function(){
           if(toggle != 1 && open == true){
               open = false;
               var panel = "#panel"+toggle;
               $(panel).slideToggle("slow");
           }
           toggle = $input;// I need this to update from php argument
           $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow",function(){

           $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#panel1").offset().top
               }, animation_time );});

           if(open == true)
               open = false;
           else
               open = true;

           return false;
       });

    "
    }
   ```

The purpose of this is that I want to build a javascript file that has a variable amount of these segments, I will have the php fully construct the javascript file that can then be used in the webpage.

EDIT:

For example:

```
<?php
$bar = 'hello';             
$tmp = "My name is $bar";
echo $tmp;
?>
```

In my code I don't want php to get confused about the $ variable, I want to make those $ in the javascript code completely invisible to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice:

- use single quotes (or, better, nowdoc on php 5.3+) to prevent excessive escaping
- encode all values that are used in javascript as json to avoid quotation/newline issues
- use mini-templating for variable substitutions

Example:

```
    $js = 
<<<'JS'
    $("#toggle1").click(function(){
        if(toggle != 1 && open == true){
            open = false;
            var panel = "#panel"+toggle;
            $(panel).slideToggle("slow");
        }
        toggle = {{input}}; // I need this to update from php argument
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow",function(){

            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#panel1").offset().top
            }, animation_time );});

        if(open == true)
            open = false;
        else
            open = true;

        return false;
    });

    return;
JS;
    $input = json_encode($input);
    return str_replace('{{input}}', $input, $js);
}

print returnJS('hi "there" ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes by putting a \ in front of them. For example:

```
function returnJS($input){

return '    

    $("#toggle1").click(function(){
        if(toggle != 1 && open == true){
            open = false;
            var panel = "#panel"+toggle;
            $(panel).slideToggle("slow");
        }
        toggle = '.$input.';// I need this to update from php argument
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow",function(){

        $(\'html, body\').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#panel1").offset().top
            }, animation_time );});

        if(open == true)
            open = false;
        else
            open = true;

        return false;
    });

 '
 }
```

Comment: How about those $'s? I know that php can affect the $ even inside a string. Is there a way to make php ignore the $ inside the string?

Comment: Thats only in double quotes, you should change the return to single quotes, I will edit my answer